# Expression pattern of type '[String]' cannot match values of type '[String]' when using a switch statement with arrays

Tags: arrays, swift, string, xcode, switch-statement

I am a beginner programmer writing my first script in swift. The script is pretty straightforward you buy an item and it gets sent to your inventory. I have run into an error while using a switch statement that takes in values from an array. the error is,

> Expression pattern of type '[String]' cannot match values of type
>   '[String]'

I was not able to find anything similar to the issue I ran into since I am dealing with [String] values.

here is the code

```
import UIKit

var money = 200
var status = ""
var inventory:[String] = []
var itemIdentifiers:[Int] = [200,400,450,600,1000,150,250,350,200,400,140,250]

func foodbasic(_ sender: UIButton) {
    buy(productName: "Basic Food", priceOfItem: itemIdentifiers[0])
}
func foodgood(_ sender: UIButton) {
    buy(productName: "Good Food", priceOfItem: itemIdentifiers[1])
}
func foodbest(_ sender: UIButton) {
    buy(productName: "Best Food", priceOfItem: itemIdentifiers[2])
}

func buy(productName: String, priceOfItem: Int){
    if money == priceOfItem{
        inventory.append(productName)
        print ("done")
    }
    else{
        //figure out how to make a "not enough money" type thing
    }

}

switch inventory {
 case ["Basic Food"] :
   print ("you got basic food")
 case ["Good Food"] : 
   print ("you got good food")

 default:break
}
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem with either Xcode 9.4 nor Xcode 10. Is this your entire code? (Try putting it in a playground.) The usual cause of "X is not X" is that you've accidentally defined a local `String` type that isn't the one in stdlib. That seems a little unlikely in this case, but if there's more code maybe you've done this.

Comment: What version of Swift are you using? (I'm not aware that matching arrays in `switch` was a feature added in a later version but still it's worth checking.)

Comment: I think this code is not a full code where you obtain such error. I can't reproduce too.

Comment: I tried to reproduce the issue on Playground(of course i removed the uibutton as sender) and the function runs without an issue.

Comment: Thanks for all the responses. I will try to check if there are any updates and also upload my full code since this is just a snippet.

Comment: I have never seen matching Ronan array in a switch like that, and remember it will only work if the array has exactly one item with that name. Try putting this in the `buy()` function instead: `print("You got \(productName)")` as this will work more generally.

Comment: Starting with Swift 4.1 (Xcode 9.4 ?), arrays of Equatable elements are themselves Equatable, and that makes the above switch statement compile.

Comment: Ok, I figured out that I was using an old version of Xcode (9.2 to be exact). I am currently updating it and will let you guys know if the issue has been fixed

Comment: Ok, the issue has been fixed. I just need to update Xcode. thanks for all the help, unfortunately, I can't upvote comments due to reputation points but I will make sure to come and upvote them once I have the points

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Swift [CHANGELOG](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#2018-03-29-xcode-93):

> **Swift 4.1**
>   *2018-03-29 (Xcode 9.3)*
>
> [SE-0143](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0143-conditional-conformances.md) The standard library types Optional, Array, ArraySlice, ContiguousArray, and Dictionary now conform to the Equatable protocol when their element types conform to Equatable.

That allows to match an array (of equatable elements) against other arrays in 
a `switch` statement, and makes your code compile.

In earlier Swift versions you can do a comparison with `==` instead:

```
if inventory == ["Basic Food"] {
    print ("you got basic food")
} else if inventory == ["Good Food"] { 
    print ("you got good food")
}
```